# http redirecting to index.php instead of https

Tags: php, http, https, redirect, http-redirect

So I need to redirect the HTTP protocol to https, my SSL is already enabled and working, but the problem is: Whenever I enter an HTTP URL, I get redirected to the index.php page of my site.

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# add trailing slash to directories and force SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$) 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# And for the files
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I think your question is duplicated, try with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193829/redirect-http-to-https-through-httpd-conf/45200080#45200080

Comment: This makes little sense, if `%{HTTPS} !=on` matches you have redirected everything to HTTPS at that point already, so when do you ever expect the following stuff (that then again tries to check if the request was still coming in over port 80) to have any effect …?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to Apache2 [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL#line-31) you can simplify your virtual host by something like that:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.example.com
      Redirect Permanent/ https://www.example.com/
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName www.example.com
       DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
       SSLEngine On
       //ALL Your specifics configurations here
   </VirtualHost>
```

This, allow you to redirect each request on port **80** to **https**.
So you juste have to configure your own directory index into the **443**'s virtual host.

Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a clue what you are talking about when you speak of configuring the directory index into 443 virtual host.

Comment: you told this " I get redirected to the index.php" i believed that was a mistake.In any case, proper HTTPS redirect are done like this.

Comment: Should I use that code inside my htaccess? and my public directory isn't htdocs, iit's public_html, can I change to that? I don't have knowledge in that area, I'm only doing that cause I'm forced to.

Comment: My example is  for  virtualhost. To have  example for htaccess check the link i provided